# JDBCTemplate giving Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, spring-boot

I'm trying to insert some values into my table and I keep getting a null pointer exception. I first thought it was because some values were null, but even with the ones which are never null give me NPE.

Here's my TwitterJDBCTemplate:

```
@Service
public class TwitterJDBCTemplate {


@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;




public void storeTweet(long id, long user_id, String created_at, String language, String message, String searchterm,
        String user_description, String user_location, String user_pic, String user_screenname, String username) {

    String SQL = "insert into tweets (id, user_id, created_at, language,"
            + "message, searchterm, user_description, user_location, user_pic,"
            + "user_screenname, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, new Object[] { id, user_id, created_at, language, message, searchterm,
            user_description, user_location, user_pic, user_screenname, username });
}
```

Here's my Main App:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class TwitterApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SpringApplication.run(TwitterApp.class, args);

}
}
```

My application.properties file:

```
server.port: 9040
management.port: 9041
management.address: 127.0.0.1

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitter

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 

spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Inside of my TweetController:

```
@RestController
@Scope("singleton")
public class TweetController {


@Autowired
TwitterJDBCTemplate template;
```

Comment: Show the full stacktrace (edit question, don't show in a comment).

Comment: In your TwitterJDBCTemplate you neither initialize nor have the Autowired annotation on the jdbcTemplateObject field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not create jdbcTemplate object at your app,that's why you are getting NPE. I think there is two posible options:

1) Add jdbcTemplate bean to spring context and autowire it.

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
   return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```

And your class

```
@Service
public class TwitterJDBCTemplate {


@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
.....
}
```

2) Create jdbcTemplate inside your class

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

In addition i bielive that it's not the best practice to use methods with big number of params. Maybe you should create your custom class Twit or smth like this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to create a `JdbcTemplate` *bean* in your application context before you `@autowire` it in your code.

You can do it for example in a `@Configuration` class.

```
  @Configuration
  public class DatabaseConfiguration {

           @Bean
           @Primary
           @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
           public javax.sql.DataSource primaryDataSource() {
                   return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
           }

           @Bean
           public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
                   return new JdbcTemplate(primaryDataSource());
           }

  }
```

According to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) tutorial. Adding this dependency will take care of creating the `JdbcTemplate` for the application.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Then you can `@autowire` as follows,

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate
```